# form select options not populating

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In a spring mvc app, the drop down list below is not populating with any values, even though the `sel_word.concepts` collection has many values in it:

```
<form:select path="conceptSelected" size="5" style="min-width:600px">
    <form:options items="${sel_word.concepts}"/>
</form:select>
```

To confirm that the `sel_word.concepts` list is populated and is being sent to the view, I:

```
1.) printed out the size of sel_word.concepts in the controller and  
2.) populated a data table in the jsp with the contents of sel_word.concepts.
```

To show you explicitly, the following table in the view populates correctly with the values of sel_word.concepts:

```
<datatables:table id="drugconcepts" data="${sel_word.concepts}" cdn="true" row="concept" theme="bootstrap2" 
    CssClass="table table-striped" paginate="false" info="false"  filter="false"
    cssStyle="width: 650px;" align="left" >
    <datatables:column title="cui" cssStyle="width: 100px;" display="html">
        <c:out value="${concept.rxcui}"/>
    </datatables:column>
    <datatables:column title="Names" cssStyle="width: 500px;" display="html">
        <c:out value="${concept.str}"/>
    </datatables:column>
</datatables:table>
```

So there are values in `sel_word.concepts` and those values are in fact being sent to the jsp.  So why aren't those values populating the `form:select` drop down list?  How do I change my code to make the drop down list populate correctly?

For reference, I have posted the full code for the `model`, `view`, and `controller` at a file sharing site, which you can access by clicking on the links below.

You can view the code for the `model` [by clicking on this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/vJCIR0pFVULXvE11kEIA?b=ePR4VNYyEcvmOqACV2Ag).
You can view the code for the `DrugWord` entity part of the model [by clicking on this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/kVyvAD00r7uGUIoWN0qu?b=efbqxrxrhv3f5pstRxdT)
You can view the full code for the `view` [by clicking on this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/4bMBkSrZHUKludLc4cQA?b=FOAnQ0xxvnlbDSGZqJhA).
You can view the full code for the `controller` [by clicking on this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/EWaw0co41vpELvTE0I8E?b=UJ4adSqccHwNaPO4rHVQ).

---

### EDIT:

As per CodeChimp's request, I am posting the html that is actually sent to the browser as follows.  This is what I got when I clicked `view source` in the browser:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="medication" method="post" class="form-horizontal" >
    <div class="control-group">
        Drug Concepts: 
           <form:select path="conceptSelected" size="5" style="min-width:600px">
               <form:options items="[1163058, 1163059, 1163060, 1163061, 1163062, 1163063, 1163064, 190521, 213460, 213461, 221052, 242679, 242680, 284620, 285028, 307650, 329484, 329485, 364596, 368153, 368253, 370502, 370503, 374813, 476143, 539824, 573348, 573349, 575077, 602392, 602393, 602394, 602395, 614534] itemValue="rxcui"/>
            </form:select>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        Dosage Text: 
            <form:input path="dosagetext" />
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        Route: 
        <form:input path="route" />
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        Frequency: 
        <form:select path="freqSelected" items="[twice daily, as directed, as required, once a day, in the morning, once a day, once a day, before bed, four times daily, every other day, once a day, in the evening, three times daily]" size="5" style="min-width:600px"/>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        Duration: 
        <form:input path="duration" />
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        Start Date: 
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        Status: 
        <form:input path="status" />
    </div>
        <form:hidden path="id"/>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit">Add this medication</button> <h3>Link to delete will go here.</h3>
    </div>
</form:form>
```

By contrast, the code for the JSP form on the server is as follows:

```
<c:set var="method" value="post"/>
<c:url value="/patientscodes.html" var="actUrl"/> 
<form:form modelAttribute="medication" method="${method}" class="form-horizontal" >
    <div class="control-group">
        Drug Concepts: 
        <form:select path="conceptSelected" size="5" style="min-width:600px">
            <form:options items="${sel_word.concepts} itemValue="rxcui"/>
        </form:select>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        Dosage Text: 
        <form:input path="dosagetext" />
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        Route: 
        <form:input path="route" />
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        Frequency: 
        <form:select path="freqSelected" items="${freqs}" size="5" style="min-width:600px"/>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        Duration: 
        <form:input path="duration" />
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        Start Date: 
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        Status: 
        <form:input path="status" />
    </div>
        <form:hidden path="id"/>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit">Add this medication</button> <h3>Link to delete will go here.</h3>
    </div>
</form:form>
```

As per CodeChimp's request, the code for mvc-view-resolver.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
- DispatcherServlet application context for knowledgemanager's web tier.
-->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
   xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"  
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm  
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm.xsd  
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">  
<!--
- The ContentNegotiatingViewResolver delegates to the InternalResourceViewResolver and BeanNameViewResolver,
- and uses the requested media type (determined by the path extension) to pick a matching view. 
- When the media type is 'text/html', it will delegate to the InternalResourceViewResolver's JstlView, 
- otherwise to the BeanNameViewResolver.
-->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="contentNegotiationManager" ref="cnManager"/>

    <property name="viewResolvers">
        <list>
             <!-- Default viewClass: JSTL view (JSP with html output) -->
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                <!-- Example: a logical view name of 'vets' is mapped to '/WEB-INF/jsp/vets.jsp' -->
                <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
                <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
            </bean>

            <!-- Used here for 'xml' and 'atom' views  -->
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Simple strategy: only path extension is taken into account -->
<bean id="cnManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="true"/>
    <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true"/>
    <property name="defaultContentType" value="text/html"/>

    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="html" value="text/html" />
            <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
            <entry key="atom" value="application/atom+xml" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Are you getting any `<option>` tags at all?  How do you know `sel_word.concepts` has items?  Have you tried specifying label and values attributes for the `form:options` tag?

Comment: @CodeChimp I added the code for the table which is populated correctly by `sel_word.concepts` in the same jsp.  I do not know what you mean by `<option>` tags.  I have not tried specifying `label` and `values` attributes for the `form:options` tag.

Comment: @CodeChimp what would your suggestions look like in code?

Comment: I am unable to view your code as I am behind a firewall/proxy that is blocking.  What I mean by `<option>` is that the `<form:options>` tag is a Spring JSTL tag that generates HTML `<option>` tags as a result.  Are you getting any in the generated HTML source and they are simply not correct, or are you getting none generated at all?  If the first, it's probably in your options being passed to the `<form:options>`, if the second then your list is empty.  Thousands upon thousands of people use Spring, so we know it works.  You have to assume it's your code and approach debugging systematically.

Comment: @CodeChimp I just added the html and the jsp code for the form to the end of my original posting above.  The html option tags are indeed being populated with a list of items.  So why can't I see them in my browser?  How do I need to change my code?

Comment: You have a configuration problem.  All of those `<form:*>` tags are all Spring JSTL tags.  Those should be processed on the server side and never make their way to your browser.  I would start by looking at how your Spring ViewResolvers are setup.

Comment: @CodeChimp Thank you.  How do I do that?

Comment: You need to check your Spring config.  This would be your web.xml plus whatever you are using to wire together Spring (app context XML file, some Java config classes, etc).  Either that, or you are returning the view names wrong.  Again, since I can't see your controller or such, I can only guess.

Comment: @CodeChimp The code is just on a file sharing site.  It is just a bunch of txt files.  Why is that deemed a security threat?  There is so much of it, that it would make my posting unreadable unless I organize it in some way, like I have with the links.

Comment: You would have to ask my employer as to why they consider that a security threat.  I am trying to help you here, but I can't see the code.  It's either a problem with how you are returning your view names in your Controller handlers, or a problem with your setup, in particular I would guess the ViewResolvers.

Comment: @CodeChimp Thank you for your patience.  I added the code for the xml config file which handles the view resolvers.  Does it help?  Please let me know which stuff to remove so that I can keep the posting clean.  I don't want to scare off others by dumping a bunch of code.

Comment: Ok, questions: 1) Are the JSP files in WEBINF/jsps as noted in the config? 2) How are you returning the view name from the controller?  Are you sending back just the name, as in "myView" or are you sending back the entire view "myView.jsp"? 3) Do you have the jstl.jar and standard.jar in your WEBINF/lib folder? 4) Are there any errors or warnings in the logs when you start?  5) What version of Spring and which app server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Make changes in your jsp as follows to include itemValue and itemLabel:

```
    <form:select path="conceptSelected" size="5" style="min-width:600px">
        <form:options items="${sel_word.concepts}" itemValue="rxcui" itemLabel="str"/>
    </form:select>
```

Comment: Thank you.  I made those changes exactly as you specified them.  But the drop down list is still not populating.  What else would you suggest?

Comment: Is Frequency drop down being displayed correctly? Can you post your DrugWord entity as well?

Comment: No, neither drop down is being displayed correctly.  I just added a link to the code for the `DrugWord` entity to my original posting above.  Does it help you see the problem?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. Looks like your view handling is fishy. Post your servlet config xml, web.xml to dig more.

Comment: I just posted the mvc-view-config.xml file above.  It is called by mvc-view-config.xml, which in turn is called from web.xml.  All of the viewResolver stuff is delegated from the other xml files to mvc-view-config.xml.  Does this help?